# Just installed python and following the installation guide. Keep getting errors

Tags: python, installation

So I just installed python 3.6.4 and I am a complete beginner and was following the [installation guide on The Hitchhikers Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/win/). I keep coming across an error where I try to add the directories for my Python to the PATH. The site tells me to run

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path","$env:Path;C:\Python36\;C:\Python36\Scripts\", "User")
```

But when I run the line in the shell, it errors with invalid syntax, highlighting the double colons between `Environment` and `SetEnviromentVariable`. When I delete one of the colons, it then errors by highlighting `User` and saying that is invalid syntax.

Comment: That's a powershell command. Are you sure you opened the powershell?

Comment: How do you open the powershell?

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-open-an-elevated-powershell-prompt-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

If All you need is to add python to your path then just follow:

open system properties from start menu -> go to advance tab-> go to environment variable -> click edit on "PATH" in system variable->
now add python to end of list(use semicolon to separate).

In your case, In the end add:
`;C:\Python36\`

Optionally if you actually need the scripts also add this too:
`;C:\Python36\Scripts\`